# How to find another basis if given one basis for a vector space?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

How do you find another ordered basis for a vector space $C^n$ over the field $R$ if one of the basis is given? 
That is, I know the standard basis for this vector space over the field is:

$\{ (1,0,...,0),(i,0,...0),.....,(0,0,...1),(0,0,....i) \}$.

But, I want to find another basis for this vector space and this new basis should not contain an $R$-scalar multiple of a vector in the standard basis. I need this information in order to determine an invertible matrix $P$ such that for any vector $v$ in $C^n$, $[v]$standard basis $=$ $P [v]$new basis.
Thanks for the help!

Comment: I'm confused. You refer to both C^n and R. Do you mean $n$-dimensional complex space $\mathbb{C}^n$ and the real numbers $\mathbb{R}$? Are you thinking of $\mathbb{C}^n$ as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$ or over $\mathbb{C}$?

Comment: Its the n-dimensional complex space over the real numbers.

Comment: In that case, keep in mind that $\mathbb{C^n}$ is actually $2n$ dimensional as a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, not $n$ dimensional.

Comment: If you just pick at random you'll get what you want (unless you're very very unlucky.) If you choose a square matrix randomly (with iid entries according to your favorite continuous distribution), its columns will form a basis with probability 1.

Answer (score 0):

Say we have a field $F$. Then any $n$-dimensional vector space over $F$ is isomorphic to $F^n$. If you have a nonsingular square matrix with entries in $F$, then its rows are linearly independent and hence form a basis for $F^n$. That's a way to get new bases.

Comment: Can you provide an example on how to do that?

Comment: Any upper triangular matrix that has no zeroes on the diagonal is nonsingular. Then if you want the leftmost column to not be a scalar multiple of $(1,0,0,\ldots)$ just do an elementary row operation to modify it. Elementary row operations only affect the determinant in predictable ways.

Comment: I am still a little confused as to how to use elementary row operations on the standard basis to get a new basis that isn't a multiple of the standard one.

Comment: If you add $(1,0,...,0)$ and $(0,1,0,\dots,0)$, then....